# jQuery - inactive tab moving text

Tags: jquery

I have a code that change page title when tab is inactive:

```
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  // Get page title
    var pageTitle = $("title").text();

// Change page title on blur
  $(window).blur(function() {
      $("title").text("Hej! Wracaj do nauki! &#128578");
    });

// Change page title back on focus
    $(window).focus(function() {
      $("title").text(pageTitle);
    });
});
</script>
```

It works fine but does not show the whole tittle of inactive tab. How can I make this .text moving to show a whole title to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a timer to move the letters one by one.

```
   var blurPageTitle = ''; // Variable to save the page title. Otherwise it removes the spaces from the title.
   changeTitle = function(){
    var letter = blurPageTitle.charAt(0);
    blurPageTitle = blurPageTitle.substr(1) + letter; 
    document.title = blurPageTitle;
    changeTitleTimer = setTimeout(changeTitle, 500);
   };
```

Just call the function when you want it to start.
To move faster reduce the time in setTimeout function, to move slower increase it.

```
    stopChangingTitle = function(){
        clearTimeout(changeTitleTimer);
    }
```

To cancel the move just call this function and it will stop.

If you need to implement it in your code it would look like that:

```
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  // Get page title
    var pageTitle = $("title").text();
    var blurPageTitle = ''; // Variable to save the web title.
// Change page title on blur
  $(window).blur(function() {
      $("title").text("Hej! Wracaj do nauki! &#128578");
      blurPageTitle = document.title+' '; // Update title with the default title * Space required in the end not to mix the first with last word.
      changeTitle(); // Start moving the title
    });

// Change page title back on focus
    $(window).focus(function() {
      $("title").text(pageTitle);
      stopChangingTitle(); // Stop moving the title
    });


    changeTitle = function(){
        var letter = blurPageTitle.charAt(0);
        blurPageTitle = blurPageTitle.substr(1) + letter; 
        document.title = blurPageTitle;
        changeTitleTimer = setTimeout(changeTitle, 500);
    };

    stopChangingTitle = function(){
        clearTimeout(changeTitleTimer);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please apply this to my code? I'm a newbie :(

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works but when title is repeated there is no spaces:
https://richbet.pl/typy/test/

Comment: Not only eats spaces, but also on animation start there's already the first letter missing - instead of starting with the whole replacement text.

Comment: @Majo I have updated it to prevent the lose of spaces. If you think this solution helped you, you can mark it as the correct answer. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

- Cache your Elements `const $title = $('title');` don't query the DOM in intervals!
- Use a recursive setTimeout on window blur
- Use the Unicode Emoji directly as  (not as representation `&#128578;`)
- Split the mod text as array and play with the array on window `"blur"` inside the timeout
- On `"focus"` `clearTimeout` and reset to the original title:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  const $title = $("el-title"); // DEMO ONLY! Use $("title") instead
  const txt = $title.text();
  const arr = [..."Hej! Wracaj do nauki!  "];
  let tOut = null;
  
  const play = () => {
    $title.text(arr.join(''));
    arr.push(arr.shift());
    tOut = setTimeout(play, 200);
  }
  
  const stop = () => {
    $title.text(txt);
    clearTimeout(tOut);
  }

  $(window).on({
    blur: play,
    focus: stop,
  });

});
```

```html
<el-title>Click and Blur to start animation</el-title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```